# How to separate ffmpeg and php container in docker

Tags: php, docker, ffmpeg

In my project, after upload video to web server I have to convert `.avi` to `.webm`. As I have read from many tutorials I can do it with `exec()` but my project is using docker.

Can I separate ffmpeg and php container or I have to install ffmpeg inside php container?

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either. Installing `ffmpeg` in your Docker image alongside PHP, and calling it with `exec()` is the easiest option. The advantage of Docker here is that you're packaging your PHP app with its dependencies, so you know `ffpmeg` will be available no matter what host you're running on.

The simple approach is limited though - you'll need to make sure your `ffmpeg` call is asynchronous, otherwise the page won't respond until the conversion finishes. And you'll need to deal with `exec()` potentially timing out on large files.

A better option would be to build a separate Docker image for your video conversion service, which runs in its own container. The conversion service could have a simple API for the PHP site to call (specifying the source and destination file paths on a shared volume), or you could add a message queue in another container, using async messaging to increase reliability and scaling options.